# Concatenate output of range function with string in R and print

Tags: r

I have applied `range` function to a character vecotor in R, as its range function it gives me the out put as the first and last character in the vector as below

```
val = range(c("a","b","c","d"))
```

where the results in variable val is

`"a" "d"`

When i checked the `typeof` and `class` of the variable `val`, the result was `character`

Now, my aim is to print in the below format.

`Range of values in vector is a to d`

This might be a very basic question, but couldn't figure it out as I just started with R. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` :

```
sprintf('Range of values in vector is %s to %s', val[1], val[2]) 
#[1] "Range of values in vector is a to d"
```

Or `paste`

```
paste('Range of values in vector is', val[1], 'to', val[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
glue::glue('Range of values in vector is from {val[1]} to {val[2]}')

Range of values in vector is from a to d
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sprintf` as

```
do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = 'Range of values in vector is %s to %s', as.list(val)))
#[1] "Range of values in vector is a to d"
```